# comma operator failed to update the input parameter for the base class construction

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which takes advantage of the comma operator in the initialization list.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    protected:
        int b;
    public:
        Base(int a):b(a){}
};

class A:public Base
{
    private:
        const int i;
        const int j;
        void inc(int & a, int & b) {a++; b++;}
    public:
        A(int a, int b):i((inc(a,b),a)),j(b),Base(a+b){}
        void print(){cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<b<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    A a(6,7);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the results to be:

```
7, 8, 15
```

but it turned out to be:

```
7, 8, 13
```

It seems that "a" and "b" was not incremented when used to construct the base class. Not sure why...

Comment: If you up your warning level, and pay attention to what the compiler says, you'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of items in the member initialization list does *not* control the order in which the members are initialized. The base class is initialized first, then the members of the derived class are initialized in their order of definition<sup>1</sup>.

Since the base class is initialized first, the `Base(a+b)` executes *before* the call to `inc`, so it sees the values of `a` and `b` before they've been incremented.

---

1. c++11, §12.6.2/10:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
> - Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> - Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.